# Can I trace registry access in WinDbg like Process Monitor does?

Tags: registry, windbg

I have received a WinDbg log and a Process Monitor log. Some of the items are shown in WinDbg and in Process Monitor, i.e. Module Load events.

I think I would also be able to trace Thread Exit events if I use `sxe -c ".echo Thread Exit;g" et` or something similar. However, I cannot think of an easy solution to trace Registry access and file load events.

**Is there a way to trace Registry calls in WinDbg like Process Monitor does?**

Preferably it would trace all ETW calls, so I also have the file accesses in my WinDbg log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think of seting breakpoints on [Registry Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as:

```
bu ADVAPI32!RegQueryValueExW ".echo RegQueryValueExW; g;"
bu ADVAPI32!RegQueryValueExA ".echo RegQueryValueExA; g;"
```

The breakpoint command string echo the break point name and then continue the program.

Comment: Yes, with some `du` or `da` it would probably be possible to print the registry key name

Comment: On 32 bit, `bu ADVAPI32!RegQueryValueExW "!handle poi(@esp+4) 4; du poi(@esp+8); g"` and `bu ADVAPI32!RegQueryValueExA "!handle poi(@esp+4) 4; da poi(@esp+8);g"`work quite well

Answer (score 1):

see
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2007/04/14/windbg-script-tracing-api-calls.aspx

unfortunately logexts has some bugs and does not work on some OS ( maybe you will need to turn off DEP )

Comment: Nice approach, but seems to hang in an endless loop of GetLastError/SetLastError. Maybe I can tweak it a little bit to not output everything.

Comment: Yes, it is this problem I've wrote.